# Ugly LaTeX generated PDF on OS X

Tags: linux, macos, pdf, latex

I have a book I am writing in TeX, which is nice, but I only recently realized how ugly my local TeX to PDF export looks:

[image: ugly on left]

For reference, mine is on left, and a random Linux box that I have access to generated the one on the right. See how much crisper it is? I'm kind of confused as to why this is.

Here is my local `pdflatex`'s version:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)
kpathsea version 6.2.0
Copyright 2014 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.6.10; using libpng 1.6.10
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with xpdf version 3.03
```

and the Linux box's:

```
pdfTeX using libpoppler 3.141592-1.40.3-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.6)
kpathsea version 3.5.6
Copyright 2007 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Kpathsea is copyright 2007 Karl Berry and Olaf Weber.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX using libpoppler copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX using libpoppler source.
Primary author of pdfTeX using libpoppler: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Kpathsea written by Karl Berry, Olaf Weber, and others.

Compiled with libpng 1.2.46; using libpng 1.2.49
Compiled with zlib 1.2.3; using zlib 1.2.3
Compiled with libpoppler
```

Edit: I just realized that the Linux box uses `libpoppler` and I used `xpdf`. Could that be the reason? How do I switch?

Comment: Interestingly, I have the opposite case: pdf generated on OS X looks good, while on Linux looks ugly. It would be interesting to know why.

Comment: @gsl I figured this out eventually and will answer this question when I have the time. But it turns out that I did not have a particular fontset (Computer Modern, I think?) installed on OS X. I have since installed the fontset and it looks better.